# Setstate on array of objects make the mapping crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the state on the first object in an array by the index.
The reason for doing this is to learn how to update a specific object inside an Array.

As soon as I update the state, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function
```

So I am probably doing something wrong when I am trying to update the array.

I would like to update the first user(either by id or index) first time I click the button.

The state:

```
this.state = {
                users: [
                {
                   "id" : 1,
                   "name": "My Name",
                   "age": 15
                },
                {
                   "id" : 2,
                   "name": "Joe",
                   "age": 35
                },
            ]
        };
```

And the render function:

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div>
              {this.state.users.map((item, index) =>
                <div>
                <div className="col-12">
                  <label name="id" value={item.id}>{item.id}</label>
                  <input name="name" value ={item.name} text={item.name}/>
                  <input name="name" value ={item.age} text={item.age}/>
                </div>
             </div>
            )}
              <button onClick={(e) => this.updateInput(e)}>Update</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Updateinput function:

```
updateInput = e => {
        var newUser = {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "NEW NAAME",
      "age" : 99
      };
        console.log(newUser);
         this.setState(prevState => ({
                        users: {
                            ...prevState.users,
                            [prevState.users[0]]: { newUser }
                        }
                    }));
    };
```

My jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/qoaj4reu/

Comment: You need `users: [...]` (arrays have square brackets; you're creating an object instead) `this.setState(prevState => ({ users: prevState.users.map(user => user.id === newUser.id ? newUser : user) }));`

Comment: Oh ofcourse, now I feel stupid. Thanks alot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use the array spread syntax `[...]` instead of `{...}` and then if you want to update the first element of that array you should do something like this:

```
updateInput = e => {
    const newUser = {
        id: 1,
        name: "NEW NAME",
        age: 99
    };
    console.log(newUser);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        users: Object.assign([], prevState.users, { 0: newUser }) 
        // '0' because the index of the first element is 0. 
        // You can also use Object.assign([...prevState.users], { 0: newUser })
    }));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Both your and Chris G's comment helped me out!

Comment: @arkhz - Happy to help. Follow Chris g's answer if you want to update based on the id and mine for based on an index.

Comment: Yeah, will keep that in mind. Marking this as the answer, I feels like both you and Chris g helped me out!